# dropping columns in sequence/range via dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has "131" columns and I am trying to drop columns that are not needed for the analysis. Usually I drop the columns by writing the column names one by one. However, I am looking for a way to drop the columns in sequence such that I don't have to write each column's name.

In the data below, let's I am interested in dropping columns `a` to `d`. How can I do this using `dplyr`?

Dummy Data

```
a = c("a", "b", "c")
b = c("1", "2", "3")
c = c("a1", "b2", "c3")
d = c("F1", "F2", "F3")
e = c("A", "B", "C")
f = c("11", "22", "33")
g = c("A11", "B22", "C33")
```

Code

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df = data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
    
# drop columns a to d
    df = df %>% dplyr::.....
```

Comment: You can learn how to use `tidyselect` syntax to select columns flexibly in the doc of `?select()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my phone so can’t format properly (apologies), but it seems like this is what you want to do - do not select a:d

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(-c(a:d))
```

```
  e  f   g
1 A 11 A11
2 B 22 B22
3 C 33 C33
```

Comment: Thanks it works, might want to edit your answer to `df %>% select(-c(a:d))` to make the code work.

Comment: Right indeed 

Comment: Yep with ! we don’t need to pass a vector 

Comment: I formatted for you :-)

Comment: Thank you! I feel like I should learn how to post the output as you’ve done too. Could you direct me to where I might find out?

Comment: Just click the `Edit` button under the answer -> there you should see how we can format.

Comment: You even don't need the `c`, just `-(a:d)`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using `!` for taking the complement of a set of variables.:

```
library(dyplr)

df %>% 
  select(!a:d)
```

```
  e  f   g
1 A 11 A11
2 B 22 B22
3 C 33 C33
```